# Twitter Widget Timeline Tweets Not Showing for User

Tags: twitter

I have a Twitter Widget Timeline that I wish to show tweets from @FurCirucs but the widget seems to show every thing else but their tweets...you can see the widget in action at http://furcircus.com/ near the bottom on the Right Hand Side. I have check the clients Profile and they tweet all the time - Here is the code I am using from the Widget...any help is appreciated...

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
href="https://twitter.com/furcircus"
data-widget-id="585787760876900352"
data-theme="light" 
data-link-color="#cc0000"
data-screen-name="furcircus"
data-show-replies="false"
width="800" 
height="500"
data-chrome="nofooter"
data-tweet-limit="5">Tweets by @furcircus</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the problem is? It's working fine for me. The reason why it looks like other people's tweets are showing up on the feed is because @furcircus has re-tweeted them?